# Name of user who generated file system event

Tags: java, events, filesystems

Does anybody know, is it possible and how can I get name of user who generated file system event (using Java 7 nio package or JNA library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filesystems don't record (and such information is not always available) user name or other credentials of the process that performed filesystem operation. Filesystem filter drivers are in able to retrieve this information synchronously (again when possible) and report it in one way or another.

However, filesystem filters are not written in Java. For example, our CallbackFilter product notifies user-mode processes about filesystem events, but we don't offer Java API to use it. If you write your own filesystem filter driver, you can create a user-mode code for it which will interact with Java on one side and with the driver on another side.